# Python Module for Session Management

Tags: python, python-module, session-management

Is there any equivalent module for session management like Perl's CGI::Session or Apache::Session ? (I know most python web frameworks have their own implementations, but I am looking for a stand alone module that could be used with any python application.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use Beaker's which is a popular library for this. [documentation](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using)

Comment: This seems more like what I was looking for - https://github.com/bbangert/beaker/blob/master/beaker/session.py - Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is a WSGI library that is somewhat equivalent to Perl's CGI module in the Python world (almost nobody uses CGI in Python), and it has basic session and signed cookie support.

Werkzeug powers [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), a minimalist web framework that I frequently use for quick and dirty stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely test this out.